# Integer and Character problem correlation matrix

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to plot a correlation matrix and I am getting this error.

corrplot 0.92 loaded
Error:
! Can't combine `ï..`  and `school` .
Backtrace:

1. corrplot::corrplot(d1)
2. tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(corr, !is.na(corr))
3. tibble:::tbl_subset_matrix(x, j, j_arg)
4. vctrs::vec_c(!!!values, .name_spec = ~.x)
5. vctrs `<fn>`()
6. vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
7. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
8. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
9. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)

```
data_complete <- data[!(data$positivity_rate=="N/A"),]

d1 <- data_complete %>%
              group_by(conference, state, school) 


d1$positivity_rate <- as.numeric(d1$positivity_rate)   
corrplot(d1)

structure(list(ï.. = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), school = c("Air Force", 
"Air Force", "Air Force", "Air Force", "Air Force", "Air Force"
), state = c("Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", 
"Colorado", "Colorado"), conference = c("Mountain West", "Mountain West", 
"Mountain West", "Mountain West", "Mountain West", "Mountain West"
), win_pct = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), Wins = c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Losses = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), pred_ranking = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), actual_ranking = c("", "", "", "", "", ""
), week = 1:6, positivity_rate = c("0.032", "0.114", "0.034", 
"0.039", "0.066", "0.092"), weekly_newcases_per100k = c("86", 
"152.8", "190.9", "486.6", "773.8", "1232"), return_to_game_after_positive_test_days = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), X7_day_positivity_rate_influencing_games_and_practices = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), req_testing_practices = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), required_72_hr_testing_before_a_game = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), no_of_games_rescheduled = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), no_of_games_cancelled = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mask_mandate = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), surveillance_testing = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), req_daily_health_assessment = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), precaution_score = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Could you post your code please?

Comment: Hi, I just posted my code

Comment: Your question is data-related so we need to see your data to answer your issue : you  can share data example with `dput(head(data))`

Comment: In your code and your data, I do not see any correlation matrix created, so corrplot can't work. Additionally, you have both categorical and numerical data, which is something that should be thought about when choosing the right method for correlation analysis

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what code to use to find out correlations between variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be several things going wrong here that `corrplot` cannot fix. To note:

- You only have six observations.
- The variables are identical in many cases (how are wins and losses always equal and why are the grouping variables always the same)?
- The data you are trying to pass into a correlation matrix is both categorical and numerical, so it gets confused trying to run it the way you are attempting to.

To show you how it works on more typical data, here is how I ran a correlation matrix using the `iris` data instead:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(tidyverse)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(correlation)

#### Create Correlation Matrix ####
cor.iris <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  correlation()

#### Run Heatmap ####
ggcorrplot(cor.iris,
           type = "lower",
           lab = T)
```

Giving me a grouped correlation with sensible data:

[image]

I think the solution here is to find out why your data looks odd, fix it, and then come back to run correlation plots when it looks better.

Comment: Thanks, I think it lies in the fact that wins and losses are columns that all my other variables are columns with data below. Any suggestions on how to address this? Also when I did dput it did not include all the variable values so I am confused on that.

Comment: This is often a video I share for sharing your data. Not sure if its what you already did but this is a visual example:
https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Also I think the N/A's are messing up my data set how should I go about removing them

Comment: As for addressing your data I can't speak for certain what is going on without seeing your data as it stands. I have only addressed the question of whether or not you can fit this data now into the correlation plot, which its difficult to do as it is.

Comment: Common options are `drop_na` from the `tidyverse` package and `na.omit` from within R.

Comment: Thanks, I will do my best to make the modifications needed

Comment: I know I cannot help with your more upper-level issues with the data on my side, but if you found my answer helpful, please upvote or accept it :)